# Regex to match left double quote preceding with unclosed left double quote

Tags: c#, .net, regex, lookbehind

Note :

left double quotation (") = &ldquo

right double quotation (") = &rdquo

My current regex is this

```
(?>=&ldquo.*)&ldquo
```

It matches the second &ldquo in here (which is right):

```
&ldquoThis is a sample&ldquo
```

It also matches the second &ldquo in here (which I don't want to happen because the 1st quote is already closed):

```
&ldquoThis is a sample&rdquoSample&ldquoTesting
```

How can I write a regex that will match every &ldquo preceding with the unclosed &ldquo

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the answer:

```
(?<=&ldquo.*)(?<!&rdquo.*)&ldquo
```

Tested it [there](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).

Ah, it fails on `&ldquoThis is a sample&rdquo &ldquoThis is a sample&ldquo`

---

My second attempt:

```
(?<=&ldquo(?!.*&rdquo).*)&ldquo
```